# graph bar from dataset1 to dataset2 D3js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

this is my code , i tried a lot of time to make a transition between the 2 datas that i created : dataset1 and dataset2 ?

```js
  var dataset1 = [3,3,7,10];
    var dataset2 = [8,7,5,20];

var sel1 = d3.select("body")
           .append("svg")
           .attr("width","100%")
           .attr("height","100%")

var sel2 = sel1.selectAll("rect")
               .data(dataset1)

               .enter()
               .append("rect")
               .attr("width",function(d,i){return 40})
               .attr("height",function(d,i){return d*10})
               .attr("x",function(d,i){return ((i*40)+i)+30})
               .attr("y",function(d,i){return 400-(d*10)})
            sel1.selectAll("rect")
                .data(dataset2)
                .tansition()
                .duration(300)
                .attr("height",function(d,i){return d*10})
                .attr("y",function(d,i){return 400-(d*10)})
```

who can help me to white the code better ,thank you very much

Comment: Where did you define d3

Comment: the code is inside a page html  ,you can add it to a html page using the following tag <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js">   </script>

Comment: Except for the typo `tansition`, your code does work (here with a bigger duration): https://jsfiddle.net/eowv1tpk/

Comment: thank very much @GerardoFurtado , i saw the difference , i did praticly all the afternoon making the graph